# Intl.NumberFormat is not supporting in Lower Versions of IE while trying to format number to remove Thousands separator with different culture

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to format number and remove thousands separator with respect to different culture ,
It is working in IE 11 but not in lower versions.

```
 var test=new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  minimumIntegerDigits: 4,
  maximumFractionDigits: 4,
  useGrouping: false
}).format(formattedNumber); //formattedNumber=11,222,33.555
```

Answer (score 0):

According to caniuse.com, the Intl api is unavailable for IE <= 10. You should look into using a polyfill, such as https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js, or another number formatting library that supports older browsers.